# Yii2 - Generate ActiveRecord Query with AND + Multiple OR

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I am trying to dynamically generate a query which will allow searching conditionally in the following manner

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col1=val1 AND (col2 LIKE '%val2%' OR col3 LIKE '%val2%');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col2 LIKE '%val2%' OR col3 LIKE '%val2%';
```

depending on an initial condition and where there are n x `coln` values in an array.

At the moment I have something along these lines.

```
if ($condition1) {
   $query = Model::find()->where(['col1' => $val]);
} else {
   $query = Model::find();
}

foreach ($cols as $col) {
   $query->andFilterWhere(['or',['like', $col, $value]]);
}

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
```

but, when `$condition1` is true, that gives an underlying query structure of

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col1=val1 AND col2 LIKE '%val2%' AND col3 LIKE '%val2%';
```

or when `$condition1` is false,

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col2 LIKE '%val2%' AND col3 LIKE '%val2%';
```

which when `val2` is populated is too restrictive and wont return anything.

and using `$query->orFilterWhere`when `$condition1 == true` gives an underlying structure of

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col1=val1 OR col2 LIKE '%val2%' OR col3 LIKE '%val2%';
```

or when `!$condition1`

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE col2 LIKE '%val2%' OR col3 LIKE '%val2%';
```

which when `val2` will return is too permissive and will return results that aren't desired.

How can I iterate over the array of extra columns and append them as `coln LIKE $value` clauses to the SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply try this :

```
$condition = ['or'];
foreach ($cols as $col) {
    $condition[] = ['like', $col, $value];
}
$query->andFilterWhere($condition);
```